# Doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations (Strapi)

Tags: graphql, strapi

Please help me with this. In my strapi graphql. How can I filter data based in nested data. I want to filter data base in relationship under tours -> tour_itineraries -> itineraries -> country -> Name.
I want to filter it by country name. So I try this.

**tours( where: { tour_itineraries: { itineraries: {  country: "Japan" } } } )**

but it gives me error

> Your filters contain a field 'tour_itineraries.itineraries.country' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Hello! Can you pelase share your models.
I'm not sure to follow your data structure. Thanks.